# What is use of posing(In Dept with example) in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to use posing in my objective c class. But i dont know why and how we can use this?. Please ssuggest me with example.

Thanks

Comment: actually `Posing` is under with in advance objective C, it is the hidden feature, it mostly used for `replacing entire class is said to "pose`, you can get the sample from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_posing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The `poseAsClass:` feature is deprecated since Mac OS X 10.5 and out of use for a bit longer. Actually I never saw a non-debugging use for the feature in any Cocoa project (on Mac OS).

It's not even ported to the 64 bit runtime, so besides for historical reasons there's little use in learning how it works.

Using categories is the modern equivalent of posing.

Comment: Thanks Dude...It helps a lot.